# How to change structure from array to object with unique objects?

Tags: javascript

Input Array

```
const data = [
  {
    name: "USD",
    value: 200,
    type: "sell"
  },
  {
    name: "USD",
    value: 50,
    type: "buy"
  },
  {
    name: "EUR",
    value: 150,
    type: "buy"
  },
  {
    name: "USD",
    value: 200,
    type: "sell"
  }
];
```

I need to create a function which will convert this array (data) to this

```
{
  USD: {
    sold: 400,
    bought: 50
  },
  EUR: {
    sold: 0,
    bought: 150,
  }
}
```

Snippet

```js
const data = [{
    name: "USD",
    value: 200,
    type: "sell"
  },
  {
    name: "USD",
    value: 50,
    type: "buy"
  },
  {
    name: "EUR",
    value: 150,
    type: "buy"
  },
  {
    name: "USD",
    value: 200,
    type: "sell"
  }
];


const convert = (data) => {
  return data.reduce((acc, item, i) => {
    if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(item.name)) {
      acc[item.name] = {
        sold: item.type === "sell" && item.value ? item.value : 0,
        bought: item.type === "buy" && item.value ? item.value : 0
      };
    } else {
      acc[item.name] = { 
            sold: item.type === "sell" ? (acc[item.name].sold += item.value) : 0, 
            bought: item.type === "buy" ? (acc[item.name].bought += item.value) : 0 };
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

console.log(convert(data))
```

But it returned me the not correct information, I don't understand how I can get the sum of the already existing item and the next one. In else I try to sum the existing value with a new one.

But not sure why it returns to me an incorrect value.

Comment: You're not summing the values, they're being replaced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is having problems because on each iteration you're a) replacing the object for each currency b) within that object either just setting the value, or setting zero - you're not *adding* to the value, just replacing it.

Here's a version using `reduce` that will work as intended.

```js
const data=[{name:"USD",value:200,type:"sell"},{name:"USD",value:50,type:"buy"},{name:"EUR",value:150,type:"buy"},{name:"USD",value:200,type:"sell"}];

function convert(data) {
  return data.reduce((acc, item) => {

    // Destructure the properties from `item`, assigning
    // `type` a new name
    const { name, value, type: oldType } = item;
    
    // Set the new type to either bought/sold depending
    // on the old type
    const type = oldType === 'buy' ? 'bought': 'sold';
    
    // If the currency doesn't already exist on
    // the accumulator add it, and set the value to
    // a new object
    acc[name] ??= { bought: 0, sold: 0 };

    // Update the value of the type
    acc[name][type] += value;
    
    // Return the accumulator
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

console.log(convert(data));
```

Additional documentation

- [Nullish coalescing assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Is `.reduce(…)` necessary here? Can it be a `for..of` loop?

Comment: Not really necessary no - a loop would be fine. But my answer used `reduce` because the OP wanted to use `reduce`. @ParzhfromUkraine

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object for getting the right property for adding the value by type.

```js
const
    data = [{ name: "USD", value: 200, type: "sell" }, { name: "USD", value: 50, type: "buy" }, { name: "EUR", value: 150, type: "buy" }, {  name: "USD", value: 200, type: "sell" }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { name, value, type }) => {
        const types = { sell: 'sold', buy: 'bought' };
        r[name] ??= { sold: 0, bought: 0 };
        r[name][types[type]] += value;
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
const result = {};

data.forEach(item => {
  if (!result[item.name]) {
    result[item.name] = {
      sold: 0,
      bought: 0
    };
  }

  if (item.type === "sell") {
    result[item.name].sold += item.value;
  } else if (item.type === "buy") {
    result[item.name].bought += item.value;
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: If you use the snippet tool `[<>]` you can make a version of this that can run, and you can test it.